# Detect that automated Chrome page has been closed

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have written code to automate entries into a survey using Excel VBA with selenium controlling chrome.
If the user closes the driven chrome window then currently I get a vba error when the next element can't be found.
I want to write some code to detect the chrome window is no longer present and then close down the vba code smoothly.
My idea was to try to find the tab title and execute the closure code if it did not exist - meaning I got the chrome not available error. The code below seems to work but there is a 13 second wait whilst it looks for the page title. Shortening any of the 4 Timeouts available in selenium basic does not seem to change this wait.
My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to check if the driven chrome window has closed?
2. Is there a way to shorten the period of time before the error is thrown?

   ```
    On Error Resume Next
    tabTitle = ch.Title
    If Not tabTitle Then
      Debug.Print "Closed"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
   ```

Many thanks

[image: The error message I am dealing with - takes 13 secs of hung time to appear.]

Comment: Update the question with the error stacktrace you are seeing.

Comment: Add in error handler and handle the relevant err.Number in that handler. So, earlier in code you will have the On Error GoTo errhand  and in the errhand: you will have the testing of err.Number and relevant code for handling. https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/tag/error-handling/   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Question edited to include error message as requested. @QHarr - thank you I think error handler would be best way. However, it takes quite a while for the error to generate (on the `drv.Title` statement) during which time VBA and Excel are hung. Can't seem to find any timeout which will shorten it.

Comment: Doesn't that particular error occur when launching? Can you show the line highlighted by debug?

Comment: @QHarr - The debug highlighted line: `tabTitle = ch.Title` (ch is my driver). Error only when the user closes the chrome page manually. To explain: The code runs in a loop. The user manually selects types of survey events they want to fill in from a menu. The automation does the rest returning them back to the menu and waits in loop for another selection. Clicking back to the home page will close the automation smoothly but clicking the close window crashes out with this error. Error handler code will work but the long timeout delay on `.Title` is what I can't adjust - see commment below.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to catch `UnreachableBrowserException`. I am not sure what Selenium version you are using, but in Java, you would surround your code in a try/catch

```
try {
    // do your Excel thing here
} catch (UnreachableBrowserException e) {
    // execute your alternate plan
}
```

The problem is that this could happen at any time, anywhere. You can simply put this everywhere on the code. If this is part of a fully-automated solution, why not simply run your script in headless mode. This will prevent the root cause of the problem which is a user unexpectedly closing the browser.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the Selenium library in VBA for Excel. UnreachableBrowserException appears not to be availalbe. Not sure if it can be run with drv.ExecuteScript?

Comment: @Saqib The best solution is to run your scripts in headless mode so that users can't close the browser. Does the execution of the script require human interaction? If so, this might be a case where Selenium might not be the correct solution for you.

Comment: Yes the user has to make some selections on the web page then the program does the rest. I can try to use error handling to do this. Do you know a way to reduce the timeout to the '.Title' not being present error message because chrome is closed?

Comment: You can try changing these `driver.setImplicitWait` and `driver.setTimeout` to lower values. Something like `driver.setImplicitWait 10000` and
`driver.setTimeout 15000` to change the implicit wait to 10 seconds and the driver timeout to 15 seconds. Obviously, I am not 100% if the name of these properties are exactly like that. But you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks already tried reducing what is available - does not seem to alter the time for this exeption:  `ch.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 1000` - 
`ch.Timeouts.PageLoad= 1000` - 
`ch.Timeouts.script = 1000` and
`ch.Timeouts.Server`